# Flask program not starting webbrowser in python

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am trying to make a simple program that opens the web browser when you go to a specific URL in flask.

I am using nginx with uwsgi, to work with flask, running on ubuntu desktop 18.04.

```py
from flask import Flask
import webbrowser
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    #this is where a new webbrowser should be opened:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://google.com") 

    return "test!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I expect a new tab of the webbrowser to be opened on the server machine but nothing happens

Comment: still looking for help guys

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a default browser set? You need a default set.

From [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/webbrowser.html):

> If the environment variable BROWSER exists, it is interpreted as the os.pathsep-separated list of browsers to try ahead of the platform defaults.

Another example from the same Python reference page demonstrates you need a window open to use `open_new_tab()` function:

> Here are some simple examples:
>
> ```
> url = 'http://docs.python.org/'
>
> # Open URL in a new tab, if a browser window is already open.
> webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
>
> # Open URL in new window, raising the window if possible.
> webbrowser.open_new(url)
> ```

Ideally, You create a controller object specifying your browser of choice from the table in that link, such as "mozilla", "chrome", "safari" etc., then use the `open_new_tab()` function on that controller.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/webbrowser.html#browser-controller-objects

UPDATE:

So I tried this

```
import webbrowser


def main():
    # this is where a new webbrowser should be opened:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://google.com")

    return "test!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I can open a new tab irrespective if a window is open.
So it works for a simple python script.

Are you saying that when you run you flask app, and try to do a `GET` request at `http://yourip-or-domain-name/test` your browser doesn't open?
(Assumption here is port `80` as you don't bind an explicit port in your `app.run()` call.

Comment: if i start python from the terminal and run it then it starts but not within the flask app, so i do have a default browser set.

Comment: i run my flask app on port 80 and i access the site through a separate machine. when i access the website through the separate machine, i want to open a webpage on the server machine. When i run it through the dev server it works fine but not the nginx one

Comment: Look into forwarding some header properties that accompany a request. not all headers are forwarded through nginx by default (I know auth headers aren't). There might be clues in nginx configuration docs, is it specific to nginx? Have to tried an alternative reverse proxy ?